# Android - how to show a snackbar containing a string taken from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment, snackbar

I have a `Fragment` with a `ListView`. When I click on a certain element on this list I want to show the title of the clicked element inside a `Snackbar`, but I get an error. How can I solve it?

Fragment method:

```
mListViewSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        View rowView = view;
        TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        Song selectedSong = (Song) mListViewSongs.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String title = "▶ "+selectedSong.getSongName();
        mainActivity.setSelectedSong(title);
    }
});
```

The method used inside the `Activity`:

```
public void setSelectedSong(String title) {
    Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, title, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    View viewSnack = snack.getView();
    TextView txtv = (TextView) viewSnack.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    txtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    snack.show();
}
```

Plus, I tested the Snackbar method for aligning the text in the center but it didn't work, why?

Log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sebbsoft.app, PID: 2080
Theme: themes:{}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.view.ViewGroup.getContext()' on a null object reference
at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.<init>(Snackbar.java:183)
at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.make(Snackbar.java:215)
at com.sebbsoft.app.PlayActivity.setSelectedSong(PlayActivity.java:354)
at com.sebbsoft.app.Fragments.TracksListFragment$2.onItemClick(TracksListFragment.java:133)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3066)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3903)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling activity's method you can directly show `Snackbar` in a fragment.
Try this in `onItemClick()` directly where you want to show `Snackbar` -

```
Snackbar snack = Snackbar.make(android.R.id.content, title, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
View viewSnack = snack.getView();
TextView txtv = (TextView) viewSnack.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
txtv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
snack.show();
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Just one more thing: I want to set the text to 'CENTER_HORIZONTAL' inside my 'Snackbar', as you can see I wrote it inside my code but it didn't work, how can I solve it?